# QLabel bad antialiasing

Tags: qt, qlabel

My problem is, that the antialiasing of the text in the QLabel isn't really good when using fonts with bigger sizes than the default one.
Platform is Windows 8.1.

Antialiasing enabled:

[image]

How it should look:

[image]

Is there any solution with the native Qt? Or could I achieve it probably with OpenGL and how?

Comment: Could you please provide any code?

Comment: What platform you are on?

Comment: As svlasov says, the platform is the most important information. If you're on Linux, check if freetype is being used.

Comment: Updatet: Platform is Windows 8.1. @EelLee Code isn't neccecary because its the usually way: Creating a font and set the styleStrategy as follow: [code]font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);[/code]